# export to excel using php

Tags: php, excel

I'm trying to make a report in Excel using PHP. Below is my code and it's functioning, but I don't get the right output that I want to appear in my Excel spreadsheet. It seems that all the data in my form is included. What I want is only the data in my database to be printed. Can you help me to solve my problem?

```
<?php 
    //this is my code for downloading my files into excel..
    if (isset($_POST['download']))
        include("db.php");

    {
        //$file="document_name" . date('Ymd') . ".xls";

        //header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");// file extension name
        //header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
        $query = "SELECT * FROM user"; 
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        $filename ="excelreport.xls";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        }

        header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);        
    }
?>
```

Comment: naming the file *.xls does not magically convert it

Comment: ahmmm .. the interface of my form . eg. the buttons, textbox and the background color of my page. @PortlandRunner

Comment: That's probably because the HTML in your page (the form, etc.) gets dumped out with excel headers. Also, you are not outputting anything from your database result. You may want to investigate PHP's [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php).

Answer (score 0):

If You like simply dump your data without any formating you should use CSV format which can be opened in Excel as well. see fputcsv() function

If You like to create valid excel file you should try PHPExcel library

Comment: how? can you give me an example.. Im really sorry Im just new in php programming. :(

Comment: Well examples should not be hard to find http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Answer (score 0):

There are some PEAR packages that make Excel export fairly easy to do. I've used it on some previous projects where I needed to export database information. Many servers already have PEAR installed, though you may need this particular package added:

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.fileformats.spreadsheet-excel-writer.intro.php